How to create a json for JSON_LISTINGS_FEED?
I'm trying to list books on amazon with feeds and JSON_LISTINGS_FEED.
But i dont know how to get my product type or what attributes I have to put in ?
I've already created the whole feeds calls and everything works but I'm lost when trying to make the JSON.
I've checked the docs:
In the use case from the use case guide docs there is no information on how to create one from nothing. And in the attributes doc it's the same thing. There is the the GitHub JSON schema too but it's the same thing from the docs so it doesn't help.
And on this page the use case link to a completely different page.

I suggest you to use a JSON validator library that validates your document against a JSON schema. Amazon's JSON schemas are really big and complex and validation logic is cascading. Without the usage of a library it may become a real nightmare. On MarketRock (disclaimer: I'm the CTO) we currently use JSONSchemaValidator.net.
I suggest you to check my series on Medium, that will guide you towards the creation of products. Right now it has 3 parts: part 1, part 2 and part 3. You should read at least the second and the third, but reading the also the first won't be so difficult.
You will also find the link to join my Amazon SP-API developer group on Whatsapp.

Your Auth tutoriel didn't worked for me and the rest of it is for putListingItem and not Feeds.
